# Azure OAuth to function app issues

Tags: azure, restful-authentication

I have a very basic function app that takes a GET and returns some static text.  Eventually I would like it to write a POST body to a queue but to keep it simple the function just returns text.  If I keep auth off, I can load the url and get a response in my browser or postman.  If I enable aad auth within the function app and create a simple app reg then goto the site in my browser I get prompted for auth and I can login interactively; no worries so far.

I would like to access the function using a secret key for application usage with no interactive login, so within the app reg I go to Keys and generate one.  This is where my problems start.  If I use postman and configure oauth using my app id and key I can get a token, I have verified this also by doing a POST to https://login.microsoftonline.com//oauth2/token directly and noting the bearer token reply.  However when I try an access my function app using the bearer token (either by manually adding an Authorization header or letting postman add it from the oauth 2.0 form) I am always denied with a 401 stating 'You do not have permission to view this directory or page.' when I do a GET to my function app.  Can someone point me in the right direction?  Thanks in advance.

Example reply from login url

```
{
    "token_type": "Bearer",
    "expires_in": "3599",
    "ext_expires_in": "0",
    "expires_on": "1525312644",
    "not_before": "1525308744",
    "resource": "https://<siteaddress>.azurewebsites.net/",
    "access_token": "eyxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx..etc..."
}
```

Response from get against function app with token

```
GET /api/t2 HTTP/1.1
> Host: <sitename>.azurewebsites.net
> Authorization: Bearer eyxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.....etc....
> Accept: */*
< HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
< Content-Length: 58
< Content-Type: text/html
< WWW-Authenticate: Bearer realm="<sitename>.azurewebsites.net" authorization_uri="https://login.windows.net/<tenantid>/oauth2/authorize" resource_id="<app reg id>"
< X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
< Date: Thu, 03 May 2018 01:12:43 GMT
```

Comment: I believe you're mixing Azure AD integration with Function Keys. The latter is a self-contained authorization mechanism and works by appending `?code=<func-key-from-portal>` to the function URL, or by passing a `x-functions-key: <func-key-from-portal>` header with every request to the function. No OAuth is involved when using function keys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you're mixing Azure AD integration with [function keys (API key authorization)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-http-webhook#api-key-authorization).

The latter is a self-contained authorization mechanism and works by appending

```
?code=<func-key-from-portal>
```

to the function URL, or by passing a

```
x-functions-key: <func-key-from-portal>
```

header with every request to the function. No OAuth is involved when using function keys.

Example:

```
GET /api/get-issues HTTP/1.1
Host: {funcapp}.azurewebsites.net
User-Agent: ajax-library-of-the-day
x-functions-key: rkW0PqT.....zcUBQ==
```

or

```
GET /api/get-issues?code=rkW0PqT.....zcUBQ== HTTP/1.1
Host: {funcapp}.azurewebsites.net
User-Agent: ajax-library-of-the-day
```

[image: Function authorization logic]

Comment: Thanks for the explanation @evilSnobu.  Makes sense I think.  I did see when you create the function app you can set the authorization level to anonymous and when grabbing the function app url it didn't have code=... in the url, it just didn't click that the code is effectively auth.  I'd buy you a coffee if I could :)