# Connect Azure VM to a azure function privately

Tags: azure, networking, azure-functions, azure-virtual-machine

I have an Azure VM running a .net MVC in which the controllers are API endpoints. What I would like to do is hit an API endpoint that is in this MVC in the azure VM. This endpoint needs an user to authenticated, but I would like to skip the authentication process when I use the azure function to hit this endpoint. Is that possible?

Essentially, since the azure function and the azure VM are in the azure infrastructure, my guess is that I should be able to hit the API endpoint in the VM with a private IP that can overpass the authentication.

Answer (score 4):

An Azure Function is able to call your VM privately if you enable VNET integration for the App Service Plan that holds the function app (Consumption plan is a no go).

Conversely, you can only call a function privately from the VM if the function is hosted in App Service Isolated, which is a pretty expensive proposition just to avoid sending a function key in the headers over the public function endpoint.

Comment: Is it possible to create a private key for the function to authenticate with the VM and the mvc project publicly? Is that something I can create via the azure function console?

Comment: Yes, add a function key via the portal, make sure your Function Auth level is not anonymous then call it like this - https://stackoverflow.com/a/50147599/4148708. Find a safe place to store that secret on your VM and pick it up when calling the function. Not private key in the x509 sense but still a secret.

Comment: Just to make sure we are on the same page. The azure function and the VM are separate. So you are saying I can create the key for the azure function, then when I call the controller’s endpoint (which is in the running in the azure vm) from the azure function I grab the key, and make that async call to that endpoint passing the key. Then I just need to make sure the MVC project running in the VM knows about this key to let it hit the controller’s endpoint. Is this right? Thanks btw!

Comment: Nope, I thought you want the opposite (the VM calls the function). Just look for VNET integration for App Service. That will call the VM endpoint on the private IP. Amend your Function code to call `http://10.1.1.6/api/something`, considering that's the VM.

Comment: You could also implement the logic from your previous comment. Store the secret in Application Settings in the function app and match it in the MVC app. I guess you just need to hook all calls in your MVC filter so it should be relatively trivial. The more enterprisey approach would be to tie in both apps to Azure AD and call the MVC app with a Bearer token.

Comment: Thanks I will do a bit more research on this. I have also updated the post to make it more clear what I want