# Access file on Azure virtual windows machine from an Azure Function

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-virtual-machine, azure-files

I want to access a virtual machine.. a file server if you will.. from an Azure function.

How do I get the azure function to authenticate with the virtual machine?

Currently the azure function and the virtual machine are on different Azure subscriptions.. but we have implemented VNet peering between the two of them.

I'm using this library https://github.com/mattjohnsonpint/SimpleImpersonation but I'm super unsure what to use :(

The Azure function code below returns "Access to the path is denied"

```
        try
        {
            var credentials = new UserCredentials("virtualmachinedomain.com.au", "andrewd", "passwordhere");
            using SafeAccessTokenHandle userHandle = credentials.LogonUser(docGenRequest.LogonType);  // Which login type to use?

            WindowsIdentity.RunImpersonated(userHandle, () =>
            {
                FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(@$"\\fileserver.com.au\WordDocToAccessOnFileShare.doc}", FileMode.Open);
                if (fileStream != null && fileStream.Length > 0)
                {
                    messageReturnedAsPartOfOkReesult = messageReturnedAsPartOfOkReesult + "Result: Able to reference file";
                    logger.LogInformation("able to reference file");
                }
            });
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            messageReturnedAsPartOfOkReesult = messageReturnedAsPartOfOkReesult + $"Result: Unable to reference file. Exception: {ex.Message}";
            logger.LogError($"Unable to reach file {ex.Message}");
            if (ex.InnerException != null)
            {
                logger.LogError($"Inner exception {ex.InnerException.Message}");
            }
        }
```

Comment: try changing the plan in the function to premium if you are using consumption refer this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50156072/connect-azure-vm-to-a-azure-function-privately

Answer (score 0):

Is your function integrate with the VNet (supported only on Premium)?

But a function trying to impersonate to access the local file system of a VM is weird. Seems to be an XY problem here.

The native file share service on Azure is the Blob Storage. You can mount a share on your Azure VM. You can also connect natively to this share using functions (or any other Azure service) without impersonation.

If you can't move your data to a Storage, then expose a service hosted on the VM that will be called by the function.

Comment: Hey @saad yes XY problem for sure.... the X being "I want to access files on a vm from my azure function"

So you're saying if I could create a file share under an azure storage account.. place the files that I need to access onto that file share... I could access that file share via Azure SDK C# for example from my Azure function? 

Also by then mounting that share onto the Azure VM... business users can still see those files / add new files into that file share... and generally browse to the file share etc like mapped network drive which how they currently see it.

Comment: Exactly, you can mount a share as network drive, and map it to a partition https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-how-to-use-files-windows.